# Remove tabs from AngularUI tabs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'd want to remove tabs in the tabset/tab directive of AngularUI.
Strangely the tab-content is removed, but not the tab ... really lost here.

I have set an example demonstrating what's happening:

Here's the crucial piece:

```
// Code is taken 1:1 from https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/tabs/tabs.js
ctrl.removeTab = function removeTab ( tab ) {
        var index = tabs.indexOf( tab );
        //Select a new tab if the tab to be removed is selected and not destroyed
        if ( tab.active && tabs.length > 1 && !destroyed ) {
            //If this is the last tab, select the previous tab. else, the next tab.
            var newActiveIndex = index == tabs.length - 1 ? index - 1 : index + 1;
            ctrl.select( tabs[newActiveIndex] );
        }
        tabs.splice( index, 1 );
        console.log( 'tabs after removing: ', tabs );        
    };
```

**What's happening:**
The tab-content is being removed, but not the tab.

https://jsfiddle.net/stefanwalther/k9n17609/6/

Answer (score -1):

You only removing the tabs in the array but the tabs in the html is not rendered by angular through ng-repeat or similar and have no bindings to the tabs in the array.

Comment: Thx, any hints what would be the best way to achieve that?